# FAKE - Start process in new window

Tags: f#, f#-fake, f#-fake-5

I am trying to launch an application in a new console window from a FAKE script.

In normal .NET code, the method `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` can be used to do this.

I've also done this in the past with CAKE, like this:

```
Task("run-myapp")
  .Does(() => {
    var info = new ProcessStartInfo {
      FileName = "dotnet",
      Arguments = "run myapp.fsproj",
      WorkingDirectory = "C:\\path\\to\\my\\app\\"
    };
    Process.Start(info);
  });
```

In FAKE, I have tried the same thing, but this starts a new background process and outputs to the console window where I run FAKE. I then later need to use Task Manager to kill that process.

```
Target.create "run-myapp" (fun _ ->
  let psi = ProcessStartInfo()
  psi.FileName <- "dotnet"
  psi.Arguments <- "run myapp.fsproj"
  psi.WorkingDirectory <- "C:\\path\\to\\my\\app\\"
  Process.Start psi |> ignore
)
```

I have also tried explicitly setting `ProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow <- false` (although `false` is the default) and this does not change anything.

Is there a way to do this in FAKE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer in the issue on this closed GitHub issue: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/21767#issuecomment-312328630

The reason is the default value of `UseShellExecute` is `false` in .NET Framework, but `true` in .NET Core. CAKE is in Framework and FAKE 5 is in Core.

Solution:

```
Target.create "run-myapp" (fun _ ->
  let psi = ProcessStartInfo()
  psi.FileName <- "dotnet"
  psi.Arguments <- "run myapp.fsproj"
  psi.WorkingDirectory <- "C:\\path\\to\\my\\app\\"
  psi.UseShellExecute <- true
  Process.Start psi |> ignore
)
```